# Gradle allow insecure repository mirror

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm starting a new project. For which I don't need any local dependencies. But in our org we use local maven mirrors that run on http. With maven settings.xml

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus-local</id>
        <mirrorOf>external:*</mirrorOf>
        <url>http://nexus-local.org.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

I tried to configure the unsecure connection in gradle to make it happy, like

- build.gradle

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://nexus-local.org.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
```

- build.gradle.kts

```
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("http://nexus-local.org.com/nexus/content/groups/public")
            isAllowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
```

But in both cases when I run gradle it just crashes with error (so the result is the same as without this configuration):

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'panic'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://nexus-local.org.com/nexus/content/groups/public)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Just faced this issue in my Org. Solved it by adding below in ~/.gradle/init.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
          url "http://artifactory.myorg.org/repo/"
          allowInsecureProtocol true
        }
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Hope this works.