# Could not resolve all files for configuration error with gradle on Android Studio

Tags: android, realm

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:10.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:10.0.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-annotations-processor/10.0.1/realm-annotations-processor-10.0.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/realm/realm-annotations-processor/10.0.1/realm-annotations-processor-10.0.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Does anyone know how to fix these problems? And below is the image for my build.gradle.

`build.gradle` project :

[image: 1]

`build.gradle` App :

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J22Ye.png) & [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVewz.png)

Comment: Have you added both `jcenter()` and `mavenCentral()` in your build.gradle file under `repositories`? The error that you get usually means that the library or specified version wasn't found. And I see that `mavenCentral()` does have this version - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.realm/realm-annotations-processor/10.0.1

Comment: Share your Build.gradle.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vcToeWrAb4ICi66YznOGsavfHrr32Ryy?usp=sharing that my build.gradle picture

Comment: Thanks everyone who has stopped by to help me resolve this issue. Apparently realm has moved its newest repository to maven central and now i'm using it

Comment: @ThufailQolbaAufar the given drive link require to ask access. Also, I see you put screen, but it's better if you copy/paste. Finally, if you find an answer, you can self-answer to share how you fix it for other that can have the same issue !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70277365 this answer works for me on macOS